# Upload file to front-end form and send as email attachment

Tags: uploads, attachments, forms

I am trying to create a front-end form that has an option to upload a CV (so pdf or word format) that I would like to be able to send as an email attachment. I've read a few articles and tutorials the most pertinent ([link to article](http://goldenapplesdesign.com/2010/07/03/front-end-file-uploads-in-wordpress)) which suggests something like this:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
  $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id);
  //in this case ('upload_file', 'null')
  }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="file" name="upload_file">
  <input type="submit">
<form>
```

In functions php:

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id, $setthumb='false') {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  return $attach_id;
 }
```

The problem is that this uploads the CV to the media library which I don't really want. I have put the rest of the code concerning the form [here](https://gist.github.com/mantismamita/7446379)

How could I take `$newupload` and attach to to an email? (Ideally in the form of an attachment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that this uploads the CV to the media library which I don't really want.

Instead of using `media_handle_upload`, try [`wp_handle_upload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload).

WordPress provides us with a [`wp_mail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) through which you can easily send an email with an attachment

Comment: Great, I'll look into it.

Comment: I accepted your answer to this question (because it answers it :))but I'm actually getting getting an error which I'll post in a follow up question.

Comment: Here is the follow-up question if you want to take a stab: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123161/file-upload-from-front-end-form-as-attachment-not-working