# File upload from front-end form (as attachment) not working

Tags: uploads, attachments, wp-mail

I have a front-end form that is supposed to allow the user to upload a CV which is then sent along with the rest of the form as an attachment. To do so I have used `wp_handle_upload()` like so:

```
if ($_FILES) {

if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    if ( $movefile ) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        var_dump( $movefile);
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    } 
}
```

The form is then sent with wp_mail after checking for errors: (`$receiver_email, $subject, $body, $headers` are all fine and can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/mantismamita/7446379)

```
$attachments = $uploadedfile;

if (wp_mail($receiver_email, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments)) {
        
    $jobs_email_sent = true;

} else {
    $jobs_email_sent_error = true;
}
```

However I am getting the following from `var_dump($movefile)` when I submit the form.

```
File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.
array(1) {
 ["error"]=&gt;
 string(212) "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini."
}
```

And natually no attachment with the email. I checked php.ini and file_uploads is indeed on and upload_max_filesize is 128M. I have tried to add a pdf and a jpg file which are both quite small.

I would greatly appreciate any insight as to what I'm doing wrong here.

UPDATE just read that for `wp_mail()` the file path has to be fully specified as in `$attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip');`
which should be returned in `wp_handle_upload();` as file.

When I var_dump($_FILES) I get:

```
array(1) {
  ["upload_file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "3.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php3aeSzD"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(53262)
  }
 }
```

My file is named 3.jpg.

Comment: when you var_dump your $_FILES, do you get proper array?

Comment: @IvanHanák yes see above.

Comment: So, according to the $_FILES array, you have your file name-d `upload_file`, albeit in your script you are getting something utterly different `$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];`

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that. I'm still not attaching it properly though. I should double test that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but I am pretty sure this is the issue:

You are trying to attach `$uploadedfile` to the email. You've set `$uploadedfile` to `$_FILES['file']`. That is a very temporary file/file location.

Once you use `wp_handle_upload` you want to be using `$movefile` instead. If you look at the [Codex entry for that function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload#Return_values) you can see that you need (probably) `$movefile['file'])`

Comment: Still getting the same error. I tried `$movefile` on its own as well.

Comment: I am sure this is in the right direction. You will need to edit your question with more detail and probably more code. As is, I can't duplicate the whole process.

Comment: I attached the whole thing in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mantismamita/7446379

Comment: You were right. It was $movefile['file']. It also helped when I used the right name for the file ;)