# upload file with front-end submission and forward the data in an email

Tags: front-end, wp-mail, uploads

I have an email set up using `wp_mail` that forwards my front-end submission data as well as posting it to the dashboard. The part that I am having trouble with is forwarding the attachment file with that email. I found this post helpful:
[File upload from front-end form (as attachment) not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123161/file-upload-from-front-end-form-as-attachment-not-working)

I can only get the email to forward a url of the image **OR** post it to the dashboard, but not both. I really need it to do both. Problem is $movefile does just that, moves it from the dashboard to the email. Is there a way to do both-keep it in the dashboard and forward with that email?

```
    //successfully uploads file to dashboard
    if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        $newupload = insert_attachment($file, $pid);
    }


    //successfully sends file url 
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    if ( $movefile ) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        var_dump( $movefile);
    } else {
      echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs this, here is my solution:

```
if ($_FILES) {

    function insert_attachment($file_handler, $post_id, $setthumb = 'false') {
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    //get url
    $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_file_paths', $attachment_url);

    $attachment_data = array(
    'ID' => $attach_id
    );

    wp_update_post($attachment_data);


    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    return $attach_id;

}

    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        $newupload = insert_attachment($file, $pid);
        //getting the url for the new upload
        $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($newupload);
    }

}
```